# Is this matrix representation right in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex

I have the following huge matrix:(taken from a latex code)
[image: v_k matrix in LatexCode]

My doubts are two:

1) whether this matrix is written rightly for a MATLAB platform?

2) how can I display the whole code in a pdf generated by writing it in LaTeX so that the whole thing does not exceed the A4 size page limit?

Comment: Assuming `x` is a [symbolic](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html) variable, you can use the function [`latex`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo ok, I get your point that to write the matrix in latex, we can use the link you have given. But, my doubt is whether the symbolic matrix in 3 variables is written rightly for MATLAB platform?

Comment: It seems to be. But the Matlab interpreter is definitely more skilled (and more patient) than a human reader is at parsing code. So you better type it out and see

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for that, my other doubt is related to the latex one. What I actually ask is, that I want to write the code statement(i.e. this same verbatim statement written in the picture) so as to display in a pdf. I used \begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}, but the whole long piece of statement jumps out of the page when a pdf is taken, How to circumvent that?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, sorry

Comment: If you make your problem reproducible/verifiable, someone may be able to help you! See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)